# Does Earth Engine store data that is in Google Maps?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps

I noticed that Google Maps has a bicycle layer that can be turned on.  Extracting this polyline layer and bringing it into ArcGIS Online would be useful.  However, I don't know how to get that out of Google Maps.

Is Earth Engine associated with Google Maps and, if so, can someone point me in the right direction to finding that data?

Comment: OpenStreetMap could be an alternative if you can't find a Google solution.